# Can't disable Compute Engine API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Removing Compute Engine API results in an Unknown error, I don't have any instance, disk, image or anything else in Compute Engine, never used and still charged me few cents for "Storage Image".

Should I close this project and create a new one?

Answer (score 3):

If you look into your Network Internet Egress in Compute Engine, it turns out that some other environment might be using compute engine to handle outgoing network traffic and calls it as "Compute Engine". Therefore the charges for Compute Engine did not stop, hence giving error while disabling Compute Engine API.

To completely stop this you can go ahead and shutdown your project, but be careful as shutting down a project releases all resources used within the project.
[You can follow this link.](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_projects)